# Load Testing a C# function

Tags: c#, performance, testing

I want to do load testing (CPU utilization and Memory Usage) for a `C#` unit test case which accepts some random string. This random string should be a new value on load. Also, the load should be based on concurrent requests. Is there any tool which can help me achieve this?

MSTest is used in the code as a testing framework.

Answer (score 1):

For performance testing you can check [Benchmark.Net](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet). Everytime I see people doing benchmark they use this. There is a memory oriented diagnoser [Memory](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/configs/diagnosers.html) but I did not use it yet. I have seen plenty of blog post using it though so it is probably great as well.